# How do I run a script every time a DVD is inserted

Tags: dvd, automount

I'd like to run a script every time that a DVD is inserted into the drive.

Ideally, it would be auto-mounted and then a script would be run.  The script would NOT be on the drive (not looking for autorun functionality a la Windows).

A command line solution would be optimal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Insert a dvd and when this screen
  pops up

[image]

- Select open with other application
  You will then see this window

[image]

- browse to your script and add and
  select it then tick the always perform this action tick box

[image]

You can change this back later by opening nautilus preferences and changing the media handling preference.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent. This is a headless box without x installed - I found information on /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-cd.rules which seems to allow me to do this as well from the bash prompt.

Comment: @todd if you update your question I will add an alternate command line solution to my answer

Comment: @Todd Or you can add an answer yourself for a cli solution. (Tip: Next time have that kind of detail in your question)

Comment: In mine (ubuntu 12.10) there is no option to run a custom command. The "media" tab is also missing from the preferences.